# Exchange online mail flows with python

Tags: exchange, python, microsoft-office-365, microsoft

We are running Office365 for our email platform.  We are a small development firm.  Most of the users are either Linux or Mac users, no Windows users.

From what I was reading, there is a way to create global mail flows only in PowerShell which we don't use.  We develop in Go or Python.  Is there an API or Framework or something we can use to add mail flows programatically?  We are now doing it manually, but we would prefer to do it programmatically.

We are looking specifically to read all global mail rules and add/update rules as needed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Microsoft [where powershell works also with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.4) ;) And nopeon serverfault.com do not do Product suggestions.. However PS is the way Microsoft likes to go. Feel free to write an interpretation to translate the things into python

Comment: I don't think it is practical to consume Microsoft 365 api's without PowerShell. Or .NET, but there's probably not a good "nail" access to the base class libraries for the "we only use Python" types.

Comment: Exchange has a quite elaborate base class library. The complexity of creating run spaces and managing pipelines and queues for provisioning and migrations can be sophisticated.

Comment: "We are looking specifically to read all global mail rules and add/update rules as needed" -- If you are talking about mail flow rule, currently there is no other method to achieve this besides using Exchange Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft 365 is very much focused on collaboration and end user,and since it's a Paas service it's very locked down. So i don't think there is a python library. They only way would be to use smtp.office365.com with tls for outgoing email.

But in Azure you can deploy a Sendgrid resource, and they do have a python library. (I have no commercial or business relationship with sendgrid)

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-python